# Angularjs $http.post gives 401 error response . Laravel with oauth2-server

Tags: angularjs, laravel, oauth

I am using [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package with `angularjs` as client. I have implemented it's password method which works fine for GET requests.
When I try to do a `$http.post` on a secure link. It gives following error with 401.

```
{"status":401,"error":"unauthorized","error_message":"Access token is missing"}
```

- This is happening only with `POST` request done with angularjs. (I tried sending access_token as both post parameter and Http header.)
- When using chrome REST app `postman` it works fine!
- When I remove `oauth` filter from `route` it works fine in angular. **So this might be a problem with [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) package or AngularJS**

I have added this code to my `filters.php` to support CORS.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
        $statusCode = 204;

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => 'http://localhost:8100',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
        ];

        return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);
    }

}); 


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //

    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    return $response;

});
```

JS code :

```
//this wprks 
$http.get(linkshare.host+'/link?access_token=Mz44ZaWffS9YlrPG08SN8ivLMI0xkCd9bcRL2tny').success(function(data) {
    $scope.links = data.links ;
    localStorage.setItem("my-local-data", JSON.stringify(data));
});

var postLinkdata =  {
    "access_token"  : "Mz44ZaWffS9YlrPG08SN8ivLMI0xkCd9bcRL2tny",
    "title"         : "Hello",
    "url"           : "http://hello.world"
};
// this doesn't work 
$http.post(linkshare.host+'/link',postLinkdata).success(function(mydata){
    console.log(mydata);
});
```

Comment: Show javascript code.

Comment: You are passing access_token parameter wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are passing GET parameter along with POST data is not correct. GET parameters should be a part of `config` object in this case:

```
// POST parameters
var postLinkdata =  {
    title: "Hello",
    url  : "http://hello.world"
};

// Additional GET parameters
var config = {
    params: {access_token: "Mz44ZaWffS9YlrPG08SN8ivLMI0xkCd9bcRL2tny"}
};

$http.post(linkshare.host+'/link', postLinkdata, config).success(function(mydata){
    console.log(mydata);
});
```

See documentation for [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).

Comment: Tried, No luck :(  still same thing.. What could be the reason if it is working with postman rest client.?

Comment: Okay solved this, now I am sending access token in Authorization header. and it works.